# How to write the volume element for a spherical shell?

Tags: volume, differential

Having a spherical shell of internal radius of $r_0$ and thickness $\Delta r$, what is the volume element?

I started calculating and faced aome differential terms of degrees higher than 1. Should I ignore them? Would it be an approximation or this is the method to write elements?

Comment: The volume element will be the normal volume element of a sphere. The Jacobian gives $dxdydz=r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$, and that can be integrated over $\theta$ and $\phi$ and from $r=r_a$ to $r=r_b$ to find the total volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of the shell is $4\pi r_0^2 \Delta r$. You can think at a solid with base surface the  sphere and ''height'' $\Delta r$.

Or you can calculate the volume as:
$$
\frac{4}{3}\pi (r_0+\Delta r)^3-\frac{4}{3}\pi r_0^3
$$

and ignore the terms that are of second or higher order in $\Delta r$.

Or you can use the volume element $dV=r^2\sin \varphi d\theta d \varphi dr$ and integrate with respect to $\varphi$ form $0$ to $\pi$ and with respect to $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: What if $\Delta r$ is big. Like half $r_0$? Then this won't work!

Comment: It works fine for large $\Delta r$ down to the "ignore the terms that are second or higher order in $\Delta r$.  That is precisely what you do if $\Delta r$ is small.  If if isn't small, the difference in the volumes of spheres in the equation above is just what you want.

Comment: It seems that the OP is asking about a volume ''element'' with a small $\Delta r$. If not than the volume can obviously be calculated integrating this volume element from $r_0$ to $r_0+\Delta r$.

Comment: I want a volume element using which I can calculate the mass of a solid spherical shell of thickness $\Delta r$. Because the density isn't uniform. I need to integrate like this $\int_{r_0}^{r_0+\Delta r} \rho(r) \mathbb{volume element}(r) dr$.

Comment: If the density depends only on $r$ you can use the volume element $4\pi r^2 dr$.